# Viewing and Removing multiple commits at once?

Tags: svn, repository, commit, remote-server

Is there any quick way to remove multiple commits at once with SVN on a remote repo?

And on seeing a file list of modified, what does `E` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove commits so much as in deleting the commit, though you can do a reverse merge and commit that.

Details on how to do that can be found in [SVNBook | Undoing changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo).

You can specify a list of commits, even non-consequitive commits by doing:

```
svn merge -c -1234,-1271,-1285 .
```

To your second question, there is no such status code as 'E'.  See the list with `svn help status`.